Python & BeautifulSoup: How to get a child tag that has no identifying information
I'm trying to get a list of links that have no identifying information within a <div> that has a class.
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageToScrape.text, "html.parser")
items = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'object'})

The issue I'm having is I'm not seeing a way (checked the BeautifulSoup Documentation) to grab a child tag once I've got the list of items. I've tried a few different 'solutions' such as
items = items.findAll('a')

items = items.select('.objects + div > a')

items = [tag['a'] for tag in soup.iselect(".objects")]

I'm feeling pretty stuck.

Help us to help you - Please improve your question and provide also a small example of input and expected output, to get more focused answers to your specific case.

You are already on the right track in parts, but you have mixed a few things.
Get the list / ResultSet directly via css selector from your soup:
soup.select('div.objects > a')

or iterate your ResulSet you still created:
items = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class':'object'})
[a for obj in items if (a := obj.find("a", recursive=False)) is not None]

Assuming the HTML look like the following, you will get only the <a> from the first <div> :
html = '''
<div class="object">
  <a>some link text</a>
  <p>some other text</p>
</div>
<div class="object">
  <p><a>some link text</a></p>
</div>
'''


In newer code avoid old syntax findAll() instead use find_all() or select() with css selectors - For more take a minute to check docs
